# OpenCV capture loops video/Does not detect last frame

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, opencv

I am capturing an avi file and processing it.  My code has worked for sometime without problem but now it does not seem to stop after the last frame of the video is captured.  Instead it keeps looping back to the beginning of the video.  I do not understand why this is happening and I can not think of anything changing with regards to Eclipse or OpenCV.  I have tried the same code on my Ubuntu pc with the same video and it works without problems.  I have even tried as much as reinstalling the OS and apps without success.

Sample code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat frame;
VideoCapture capture;
const string inputVideo = argv[1];


char buff[PATH_MAX];
getcwd( buff, PATH_MAX );
std::string fileName( buff );
fileName.append("/");
fileName.append(inputVideo);


capture.open(inputVideo);

while(true)
{
    capture >> frame;

    if(!frame.empty())
    {
        imshow("frame", frame);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
        break;
    }

    int key = waitKey(10);
    if((char)key == 'c')
    {
        break;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

I am running this on a Mac OS X (10.8.2), Eclipse Juno, and OpenCV 2.4.3.

Any advice or comments are appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try the C style video reading with CvCapture ?

Comment: @rotating_image I have just tried that without success.  I used the code from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872383/how-to-write-a-video-file-with-opencv) and took out the code for writing the output to keep it simple.  Still loops.

Comment: I am currently having the same problem. There is a workaround though. You can just get the number of frames in the video and use a for loop instead of a while loop. This will return the number of frames: `capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)`

Comment: @zackg Thanks for the suggestion.  I had thought about doing something like that to just get by.  If at some time I come across the reason for this problem I will be sure to let you know as well. Thanks again.

Comment: This did not work for me, but I found another workaround: capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) before and after frame grabbing, if the value "after" is less than the value "before", then I've reached the end of the video.

Comment: @GB Very logical approach. Thanks, it is a viable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that I used was posted as a comment by @G B.  I am creating a solution so that it may be marked as one.

I used `capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)` before and after frame grabbing, if the value "after" is less than the value "before", then I've reached the end of the video.

Comment: I'm getting the value "after" as equal to the value "before" when I reach the end of the video fwiw (opencv 3.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Get the frame count like below,

```
int frameCnt = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
```

And check to exit the loop when the frame count exceeds..

Comment: I am sure that you mean to exit the loop when the current frame accumulator exceeds the frame count...